# Only display the first 36 chacters of a specific line from a text file

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am currently reading a text file speedtest.txt to display the results of the test.  The file is pretty long and I only need part of the information from one line to display in a textblock.  The code looks like this

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("c:\temp\logs\speedtest.txt")
        If line.Contains("MB/s") Or line.Contains("KB/s") Then
            TextBlock1.Text &= line & vbNewLine & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next line
```

And the output looks like this:

2015-01-26 08:39:45 (1.29 MB/s) - 'test10.zip' saved [11536384/11536384]

But all I need is this:

2015-01-26 08:39:45 (1.29 MB/s)

Any help or advise would be great.  Thanks to everyone is advance.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone!  I got what I needed.  The new code looks like this

```
'Search speedtest.txt for Speed Test Results and update to textblock1
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("c:\temp\logs\speedtest.txt")
        If line.Contains("MB/s") Or line.Contains("KB/s") And line.Contains("saved") Then
            Dim speed As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(line, 34)
            TextBlock1.Text &= speed & vbNewLine & vbCrLf
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I'm guessing what you actually want to do is find the index of the first `)`, and only take the characters up to and including that one. Otherwise, if you have a really large size like `123,456.78 MB/s`  then it will get cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB has a function called LEFT which returns the left part of a string.

```
Left(line, 36)
```

Comment: See @Rachel's comment in the question, the poster really doesn't want 36 characters because the speed of the download is likely to be variable.

Comment: This worked as I needed it to.  The front of the line never gets bigger than 34 Characters.  I had to put an Exit For at the end until I can fix a bug where the speed test loops and the line keeps writing.  The edited code is now in my Original Post.

Answer (score 1):

You can find, the index of hypen first, then get the substring

```
Dim myText = "2015-01-26 08:39:45 (1.29 MB/s) - 'test10.zip' saved [11536384/11536384]"
myText.Substring(0, myText.IndexOf(" - "))
```

Output will be:-

```
2015-01-26 08:39:45 (1.29 MB/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use regex since you have an idea of what you want and also since you have a limit of 36 Characters I thing you need to also do counting before outputing it.

Please see this on how to use regex.

http://www.codemag.com/Article/0305041

Comment: An example would help as the OP may not know regex syntax.